# Mosfet switching circuit

Tags: electrical-engineering, power-electronics, circuits

I am trying to make a **MOSFET** switching circuit where its gate input is 12V clock pulse. Now when I put the load between (Vdd) and (Drain), there is no drop voltage VDS, but when the gate input falls down to 0, there still a voltage between (Vdd) and (Drain) (across the load).  - - - - - - case (1).

When I put the load between (Source) and (Ground), the situation is reversed so that there is a voltage drop VDS, but when the input falls down to 0 the load voltage also becomes 0 (pulled down) . - - - - - - case (2).

Now what is better, putting the load on case 1 or case 2 ?

Comment: this probably fits better on electronics.stackexchange.com

Comment: What is the part number for the MOSFET?

Comment: part number "IRFz23N"

Comment: Is this part from Vishay https://www.vishay.com/docs/91340/sihfz20.pdf

Comment: I think so ....

Comment: What is your VDD? Can  you share your bias circuit? Also take a look at [MOS: Transfer Function, Bias, and Small Signal Model](http://aries.ucsd.edu/NAJMABADI/CLASS/ECE102/11-W/NOTES/ECE102_W11-LecSet-2.pdf)